# Jetty - servlet call gives directory index for no apperent reason

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

jetty is doing weird things. It basically shows me an directory index for a servlet. One with almost same web.xml and context xml works fine. here my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Coflight</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.codeliners.coflight.Coflight</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Coflight</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my context xml is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/coflight</Set>
    <Set name="war">/mnt/K/coding/JCoflight/out/artifacts/JCoflight_war/Coflight.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

the file structure in the war:

```
\ WEB-INF
  + classes
  | \ org
  |   \ codeliners
  |     ... (you get the point)
  \ web.xml
```

---

Solved: I have no idea why, but restarting Jetty for like the tenth time fixed it somehow

Comment: you are invoking which url? which version of jetty?

Comment: Some advice.  Upgrade Jetty, you are using Jetty 6 (or older), which are all end of lifed.  Also, do not use UTF-16 on your web.xml, stick with UTF-8, US-ASCII, or ISO-8859-1 for compliance with the servlet spec.  Lastly, if running Jetty on unix from a Jetty bundle provided by your distribution, be aware that there are other processes that monitor your logs, `/tmp` dir, mount space, and pids of your running servers and can often "help" you out by doing something that isn't beneficial to you.